# GoDaddy. Как указать данные компании во Whois при включенной функции приватности?

Tags: домен

Я системный администратор, у меня есть заказ сделать сайт. Домен куплен в godaddy.com на физическое лицо. На домене включена функция бизнес-регистрации и конфиденциальности. Если проверять сайт в Whois, то во всех полях registrant указаны данные Domain By Proxy. Один из контрагентов попроси указать в Whois данные компании: название, адрес и телефон. Отключать функцию приватности нельзя, потому что данные физического лица, на которого зарегистрирован сайт не должны быть видны в Whois. Как при включенной приватности указать в Whois данные компании?

Comment: Вопрос не относится к тематике SO.

Comment: @Regent, на Meta же вроде однозначно решили, мол вопросам по системному администрированию на русском Stack Exchange - быть. По крайней мере до тех времен, пока не появится русский Server Fault.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov вот только можно ли его к системному администрированию отнести вообще? Или же всё же речь про проволочки с компанией-хостером?

Comment: Это вопрос в техподдержку домен-регистратора.

Comment: @Regent, ну если убрать из вопроса godaddy.com, то суть вопроса не изменится. Это скорее просто общий вопрос про доменные имена.

Comment: @Regent , по-моему, это скорее вопрос о том, как совершить мошенничество, подставив во whois недостоверную информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Что бы владельцем оставалось физическое лицо - никак.

Попросите владельца домена передать его компании, и после передачи отмените Private Registration.